# Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: php, symfony

When I checked the operation with Symfony3.4, the following error occurred.
The error occurred when I sent an email to the registered email address when I forgot my password and clicked on that URL.
The following note was given to PHPStorm.
Do you have any idea?

Error

```
//Symfony
Call to a member function getId() on null

//PHPStorm
Potentially polymorphic call. The code may be inoperable depending on the actual class instance passed as the argument.
```

BaseImageController.php

```php
    public function createUploadForm(ImageService $imageService, $uploadUrl)
    {
        $image = new Image();

        //Error code
        $image->setCreatedStaffId($this->getStaff()->getId());

        // Registration csrf
        $uniq = uniqid();
        $token = $imageService->getImageToken($image->getCreatedStaffId(), $uniq);

        // Form generation
        return $this->createForm(UploadType::class, $image, array(
            "action" => $uploadUrl,
            "uniq" => $uniq,
            "token" => $token,
        ));
    }
```

BaseController.php

```php
abstract class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     *
     * @return Staff|object|UserInterface
     */
    public function getStaff()
    {
        return $this->getUser();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Shop 
     */
    public function getShop()
    {
        if ($this->getStaff()) {
            return $this->getStaff()->getShop();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Image.php

```php
/**
 * Image Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"comment"="Staff ID"})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * Registered staff ID
     * @var integer $createdStaffId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_staff_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"comment"="Registered staff ID"})
     */
    protected $createdStaffId;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set createdStaffId
     *
     * @param integer $createdStaffId
     * @return Staff
     */
    public function setCreatedStaffId(int $createdStaffId)
    {
        $this->createdStaffId = $createdStaffId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdStaffId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCreatedStaffId()
    {
        return $this->createdStaffId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$this->getStaff()` not null? check it.

Comment: @NoNAME Thanks for your comment.
When I tried it, I got an error saying it was null. PHPStorm notes ```Expected parameter of type'int',' Staff | object | \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface' provided```.